# Help Identify this Blue LED

Tags: led, diodes, identification, surface-mount

Please help in identifying this blue LED, around 470nm, 3030 SMD. Has this kind of "strong blue" phosphor coating. Very interesting piece and can't seem to find it. Any help appreciated.

[image: front]
[image: front2]
[image: back]
[image: front3]

Comment: This is a blue LED. What does it do? It shines blue.

Comment: It could be a UV 1W 3030 LED with Blue Phosphor conversion but 470 is not a deep blue, more Azure colour than turquoise. 455 would be deep blue.

Comment: Looks like a poor thermal design with tiny solder pads. a good design would have the Cathode covering 80% of the bottom.

Comment: unless you need $500 ~ $1k MOQ, these will be hard to find

Comment: This sort of thing is pretty easily available in China, at least if you're a bit flexible about the case (eg. 5050).

Comment: To identify the exact part will be pretty much impossible. If you are looking for a replacement from a well-known vendor, then Osram seem to have lots of similar parts.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help out. It comes from a Moritex MCEL-CB8 coaxial led illuminator. I was just curious if someone recognizes this part. Greatly appreciate your input.